# JSON deserializer inherited generic type

Tags: c#, json, generics, serialization, json.net

I have a problem with deserializing some JSON string into c# objects.

Let's assume i have the following code:

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public ObservableCollection<A> As
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And i serialize the following object `_c`:

```
C _c = new C();
_c.As.Add(new B() { Name = "Max", Age = 4 });
```

This works pretty well.

But i am not able to deserialize the created JSON-string and create instance of B, because the `ObservableCollection` is declared with `A` as generic type. Is there some way to tell Newtonsoft.Json to use `B` instead of `A`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would have thought that Json net used the instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem with writing a custom JsonConverter:

```
public class BCJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var currentType = (existingValue as System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<A>);

        currentType.Clear();

        var des = serializer.Deserialize<IList<B>>(reader);

        foreach (var toAdd in des)
        {
            currentType.Add(toAdd);
        }

        return currentType;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

And

```
public class C
{
    public virtual ObservableCollection<A> As
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class D : C
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(BCJsonConverter))]
    public override ObservableCollection<A> As
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you solved it but you can achieve same thing by changing your class `C` constraint, without using any custom JSON converters. See below:

```
public class C<T> where T : A
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> _as = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    public ObservableCollection<T> As
    {
        get { return _as; }
        set { _as = value; }
    }
}
```

And then de/serialize like

```
var _c = new C<B>();
_c.As.Add(new B() { Name = "Max", Age = 4 });

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_c);
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<C<B>>(serialized); // B
```

Comment: Thank you, seems also good. But this only works if i have access to `C` and it is not in a third party library.

Comment: Ok, you left that detail out in your question :)

Comment: @BendEg *"But this only works if i have access to C and it is not in a third party library"* - how do you propose adding the `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(BCJsonConverter))]` attribute from your solution to a third party library?

Comment: Ok, i have to complete my answer. `As` is a virtual method which get's overriden in class `D`, which inherit from C. I updated my answer. Sorry for that lack of information...